# Bootstrap columns not lining up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a website that uses the Twitch API and posts which users, from a predetermined array of 7 users, are online and which are not. It pretty much works, but at the moment, the edges of my top div are not lining up with the edges for my list of users.

Here's a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/YVZQMG

[image]

And here's some of my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 head">
      <span class="title">
        Twitch Streamers
      </span>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td id="all">ALL</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="online">ONL</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="offline">OFF</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="result">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$blue: #5D6E81;
$gray: #68636B;
$khaki: #B7D0B9;
$title: #F1EBF2;

img {
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}

line {
  background-color: $title;
  height: 5px;
}

table {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.act {
  background-color: $khaki;
  margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 15px;
}

.desc {
  color: $gray;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.desc2 {
  color: $title;
}

.head {
  background-color: $gray;
  color: $title;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px 0px 10px 25px;
}

.inact {
  background-color: $blue;
  margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 15px;
}

.inact a, inact a:hover {
  color: $khaki;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif; 
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Is there anything I can do with this existing code to make sure the width of the top div is aligned with the results? Or do I need to rework it?

(As a note, I did have it aligned with previous code using a single row and putting each result in a "col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" class, but this created another problem which was I couldn't make each result's img, user name, and status be vertically aligned with each other, which I would prefer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accidentally closed your `.container` before the results. Remove the `</div>` immediately above the `#results` wrapper, paste it further down, and it all lines up: https://codepen.io/mayersdesign/pen/GmWyWy

Comment: No problem. In fact DON'T paste it further down, it's a superfluous </div>... just remove it ;)